# How to track a website via Android App

Tags: android, oauth, google-analytics

There is given solution for tracking Android App with [Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/Android.html).
Is there any way to track a website via Android application? 
so we can see report, like number of hits on website, in our Android Device.
Any Solution to this problem?

**Update**

```
public class AnalyticsTest {


      private static final String CLIENT_ID = "MY_CLIENT_ID";
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "MY_CLIENT_SECRET";
    private static final String REDIRECT_URL = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "test";
    private static final String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics";
// TRIED AS WELL private static final String SCOPE = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds";
    private static final String TABLE_ID = "MY_TABLE_ID";

    public static void main() throws IOException {
            NetHttpTransport netHttpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JacksonFactory jacksonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
            // Generate the URL to send the user to grant access.
            String authorizationUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl(CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URL, SCOPE).build();

            // Direct user to the authorization URI.
            System.out.println("Go to the following link in your browser:");
            System.out.println(authorizationUrl);

            // Get authorization code from user.
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("What is the authorization code?");
            String authorizationCode = null;
            authorizationCode = in.readLine();

            // Use the authorization code to get an access token and a refresh
            // token.
            AccessTokenResponse response = null;
            try {
                    response = new GoogleAccessTokenRequest.GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant(netHttpTransport, jacksonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, authorizationCode, REDIRECT_URL).execute();
                    System.out.println("Responseeeeeeeeee "+response);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Use the access and refresh tokens to get a new
            // GoogleAccessProtectedResource.
            GoogleAccessProtectedResource googleAccessProtectedResource = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(response.accessToken, netHttpTransport, jacksonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, response.refreshToken);
            System.out.println("================== "+googleAccessProtectedResource.getClientId());




            Analytics analytics = Analytics
                            .builder(netHttpTransport, jacksonFactory)
                            .setHttpRequestInitializer(googleAccessProtectedResource)
                            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
            //System.out.println(analytics.management().accounts().list().execute());

            Get apiQuery = analytics.data().ga().get(TABLE_ID, // "ga:" + Profile
                            // Id.
                            "2011-09-01", // Start date.
                            "2011-12-23", // End date.
                            "ga:visits"); // Metrics.

            try {
                    GaData gaData = apiQuery.execute();
                    // Success. Do something cool!

            } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
                    // Catch API specific errors.
                    e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Catch general parsing errors.
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

I am using the above code for getting the analysis report from google analytic sites. 
And i got all jar files from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup) But unable to find the jar for **Analytics** it is showing me error. Please suggest me what i am doing the wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of services you can choose from:

1.[Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/index.html):
Flurry Analytics delivers powerful insight into how consumers interact with your mobile applications in real-time. Over 60,000 companies have chosen Flurry Analytics to use in more than 150,000 applications across iOS, Android, Blackberry, Windows Phone, JavaME and HTML5.

2.[Google Analytics Mobile](http://code.google.com/intl/zh-CN/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/overview.html)

3.[Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know about these thing, but need a solution for tracking a website not for our android application.

Answer (score 1):

You could install an app like one of these:

- [gAnalytics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.e6bapps.ganalytics)
- [DroidAnalytics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidanalytics)

Is that what you mean?

UPDATE

To roll your own app using the Google Analytics API, start here: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/.

A few clicks in and you may arrive at the [Core Reporting API Overview](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v3/gdataGettingStarted.html). That may have what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes shanabus it is quite similar with the gAnalytics App, Thanks for your response. Can you please let me know how can we implement this?

Comment: Hi shanabus, Thanks a lot, it really help me. But i am stuck with a problem, can you please see my updated question.

Comment: That completely changes your question

Comment: I am sorry if there is not clarity in my question, Actually now what i  am doing, i am just retrieving the information for the Google Analytics site. which may have a site information report or app information report. if you need any clarification please let me know.